# How to determine the default probability of a county in a bond that is not in its native currency?

Tags: bonds, government, probability, default

Consider the following case:

Country P uses the currency **Euro** and gives p percent interest on a one year bond issued in **Euro**.

Country Q uses the currency **TL** and gives q percent interest on a one year bond issued in **Euro**.

### Question:

How can we determine the probability of default of the country Q with respect to P ?

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/22368/5733).

Comment: @BobJansen You have given the link of this question. Plus, I asked the question first in here, and second in Quantitative Finance SE, and stated there that I have cross posted, see https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/40230/how-to-determine-the-default-probability-of-a-county-in-a-bond-that-is-not-in-it

Comment: I can't edit any more. The goal of pointing out that something is cross-posted is that users on both sites can check whether the question already has an answer on the other site. NB: Cross-posted is discouraged in general, also when disclosed.